# Pandas- Unnecessay values included while converting a column into datetime format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, machine-learning

I made a column by concatenating integers and converting into string format. Later I am converting the string column into datetime, everything is working just fine except an additional day field is added to the new datetime column. Here is what I mean to say.

```
 I am making a column of type string like this,
 '1-1992' where 1 reflects month and 1992 reflects year
```

But, when I am converting the column with "Month-Year" to datetime format,an additional "Day" field is getting added to the new column, here is what it looks like.

```
 "1992-01-01" (last 01 is added to all the values,which i don't want,
               I only want month and year keeping datetime format -
                with me).
```

How can I get rid of the last 01 which is present in all the rows, keeping the format to datetime ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
df[date_column] = df[date_column].apply(lambda x : datetime.datetime.strftime(x, "%Y-%m"))
```

Comment: Thank you for the input, it seems to work but this is changing the format to "object" , I want to keep the datetime format with me , as it is easy to plot with datetime format.